# SQl Update from table of random Names

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have a table of random names, simply 3 columns(`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`).

I am trying to have SQL update an entire table of names with a random selected name from this table.

Here is the SQL i am using. It seems to work for some of the records, but it doesn't always do all of them, sometime leaving NULLS, or not always updating all rows.  Sometime it runs affecting 9 rows, other times it says affected 11 rows... thoughts?

```
update TestNames,rndnames
set TestNames.fname = rndnames.FirstName,TestNames.lname=rndnames.LastName
where rndnames.ID=floor(1+(rand()*600))
```

answer:

```
update
TestNames left join 
(select ID,
floor(1+(rand()*600)) as rndid
from TestNames) as TN on TN.ID=TestNames.id
left join rndnames on TN.rndid=rndnames.id
set TestNames.fname=rndnames.FirstName,TestNames.lname=rndnames.LastName
```

Comment: And you have all 1 through 600 random name records?

Comment: Does the range of values generated by `floor(1+(rand()*600))` actually match real rows in `rndnames`?

Comment: Yes, there are exactly 600 records, filled in with auto increment ID from 1 to 600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update
TestNames left join 
(select ID,
floor(1+(rand()*600)) as rndid
from TestNames) as TN on TN.ID=TestNames.id
left join rndnames on TN.rndid=rndnames.id
set TestNames.fname=rndnames.FirstName,TestNames.lname=rndnames.LastName
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query:

```
update TestNames t cross join
       rndnames r
    set t.fname = r.FirstName,
        t.lname = r.LastName
    where r.ID = floor(1+(rand()*600));
```

It only updates a row in `testnames` when the random id chosen by the expression matches an id in the table.  Are the `id` values in `rndnames` all populated?

If your table is not very big and it has an `id`, here is another approach:

```
update TestName t join
       (select t.*,
               (select id from rndnames order by rand() limit 1) as rndid
        from testname t
       ) tr
       on t.id = tr.id join
       rndnames r
       on t.rndid = r.id
    set t.fname = r.FirstName,
        t.lname = r.LastName;
```

EDIT:

I think this will also work:

```
update TestNames t cross join
       rndnames r
    set t.fname = r.FirstName,
        t.lname = r.LastName
    where r.ID = (select id
                  from rndnames
                  order by rand()
                  limit 1
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, ultimitetly how you had typed did not work, but i took your idea for the fix.
YOur first response did the exact same problem as mine did, was only getting a few of the records, the last two errored out for different reasons, but the answer i posted in mine, i think is what you were trying to get out, but instead of selecting 1 random record from the random names, i first assigned a random number to each record, then joined them.

Comment: @Schugs . . . I don't think your revised query is any more likely to work for all rows than the original query.  The key to these queries is extracting a valid `id` from the `rndnames` table, not generating one in what doesn't appear to be the exact range of values.